# How to add a common control on all my Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a style to modify all my windows and add some controls to it.

My Window looks like this:

[image: wpf window]

I want to make it look like this:

[image: wpf window with style]

By applying a style so I don't have to duplicate code across all my windows.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.creat a resource dictionary**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="winStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <DockPanel  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid Height="200" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Foreground="Black" Content="notifications container"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**2.add the dictionary to every window.resource and set styles**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication21.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Style="{DynamicResource winStyle}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Comment: That is nearly perfect, I just need to keep the window content as well. I guess for that I can use the `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: that's correct @BrunoLM, probably `<DockPanel  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" LastChildFill="True"> <!--button etc here with DockPanel.Dock="Top" --> <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top"> <Label Foreground="Black" Content="notifications container"/> </Grid> <ContentPresenter/> </DockPanel>` is what you can try.