# how to set style to window with ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've creat a ResourceDictionary named `Dictionary1.xaml`, here is code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I ref it in App.xaml or MainWindow.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>

 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
 </Window.Resources>
```

And in View Designer, window's background changes to red, but when the application is running, it's background is default(white), why? How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set other controls' style in this way,except `Window`! try to set sytle for Button,Lable and so on, you will get a correct result. But for a Window, you will not.

see my another answer ,it may help you: [How to add a common control on all my Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298599/how-to-add-a-common-control-on-all-my-windows/25298707#25298707)

you must set the Style's `x:Key` and set the Window's style explicitly:

`Style="{DynamicResource key_name}"`

why the View Designer shows a correct result? it may be a bug. vs2012/13's xaml Designer has many bugs, you can search or commit in msdn.I've commit one in it :

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/925324/multibinding-report-an-issue-on-latest-vs-xaml-editor

but ms closes it and they will not repaire it recently.